# "increases" noun form pronunciation

Tags: grammatical-number, pronunciation

If it's pluralized (increases), should the stress still be on the first syllable?

[**IN**-krees] 
[**IN**-krees- es]

Answer (score 1):

The phenomenon you are talking about is described in this article from Wikipedia (and lots of other places):

> Initial-stress-derived noun
>   From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
>   Initial-stress derivation is a phonological process in English that moves stress to the first syllable of verbs when they are used as nouns or adjectives. (This is an example of a suprafix.) This process can be found in the case of several dozen verb-noun and verb-adjective pairs and is gradually becoming more standardized in some English dialects, but it is not present in all. The list of affected words differs from area to area, and often depends on whether a word is used metaphorically or not. At least 170 verb-noun or verb-adjective pairs exist...

Anyway, our tendency to stress the first syllable of a nominalization (an noun formed from a verb) does not change when you make the noun plural. So, when used as a noun, the stress would still be on the first syllable.

Answer (score 0):

For 2 exact words being able to be noun and verb, the general rule is that for nouns, stress on the first syllable, and for verbs, the second.

So yes, you are correct.

Comment: Is that the question?  As I read it the question it is not about stress but about the number of syllables. If that is the question, the answer is "three".

Comment: It asks which syllable the stress should be on